# How to put up an off-the-shelf https to http gateway?

Tags: apache, http, https, webserver, gateway

I have an HTTP server which is in our internal network and accessible only from inside it. I would like to put another server that would listen to an HTTPS port accessible from outside, and forward the requests to that HTTP server (and send back the responses via HTTPS). I know that there are several ways to do this with some programming involved (and I myself made a temporary solution with Tomcat and a very simple servlet I wrote), but is there a way to do the same just plugging parts already made (like Apache + modules)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Apache look into mod_proxy.

[Apache 2.2 mod_proxy docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

[Apache 2.0 mod_proxy docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is the sort of use-case that [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) is designed for. There is a specific [example](http://www.stunnel.org/examples/https_windows.html) of using stunnel to wrap an HTTP server.

You should consider whether this is really a good idea, though. Web applications designed for use inside a corporate firewall are often fairly lax about security. Merely encrypting the connections prevents casual eavesdropping, but does not secure the site. If an attacker finds your outward facing server and starts connecting to it, they can still try to find exploitable flaws in the web service (SQL injection, cross-site scripting, etc).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the risks, I plan to also add rules to the HTTP server so that only some specific URLs will be available to the outside connection.

Answer (score 0):

To put up an off-the-shelf HTTPS to HTTP gateway, you can use a reverse proxy server like NGINX or Apache. This allows you to route traffic from an HTTPS site to an HTTP site. For example, if you wanted to route traffic from an HTTPS site for [r2parking](https://theparkingarea.com/) to an HTTP site for r2parking, you could configure the reverse proxy server to listen on the HTTPS port (443) and forward requests to the HTTP port (80) for the r2parkingword domain. This way, visitors to the HTTPS site would be able to access the HTTP site

Comment: Hi, your answer may be useful; however, please note, original question is asked 14 years ago, and already has an accepted answer